# optaplanner vrp file with road time and time window

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to create VRP file which defines a problem with time window and distance in seconds. I currently do not need capacity (can I turn it off?)

this is my file :

```
NAME: almirs-test
COMMENT: Generated for OptaPlanner Examples
TYPE: CVRPTW
DIMENSION: 2
EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE: EXPLICIT
EDGE_WEIGHT_FORMAT: FULL_MATRIX
EDGE_WEIGHT_UNIT_OF_MEASUREMENT: sec
CAPACITY: 125
NODE_COORD_SECTION
0 0 0 BRUSSEL
55 1 1 ANTHISNES
EDGE_WEIGHT_SECTION
0.0 1
1 0.0
DEMAND_SECTION
0 0 0 100 0
55 1 0 10 1
DEPOT_SECTION
0
-1
EOF
```

it is corcectly parsed, and I see locations on screen, but when I try to solve it I get message : "Not feasible"
org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.solver/arrivalAfterDueTime/level0/[ANTHISNES]=-990

any idea what am I doing wrong? any samples where I can see how it is done?

thanks
almir

Comment: Looks like it's arriving at ANTHISNES 990 (seconds or milliseconds or some other unit) after the window closes there. I presume there's a discrepancy in the unit of measurement of the time window and the edge distances. Check the VehicleRouterImportant code (if it's indeed a bug, create a jira issue or even better send in a PR to fix it ;).

Comment: HI  Geoffre, yes that was the problem thanks. I assumed that EDGE_WEIGHT_UNIT_OF_MEASUREMENT: sec is used for all time units but it is used only for edges but not for DEMAND_SECTION. I do not know  if this is a bug as it states it is unit only for edges, so I guess it is simply my missunderstanding.  If you post your comment as an answer I would accept it. thanks!